# What is $U^2$ and $U^{-1}$ called in a (topological) group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, topological-groups

If $G$ is a group and we have subsets $S,T\subseteq G$, then we define the [*product* of these subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets) as
$$ST=\{st; s\in S, t\in T\}.$$
(Maybe for abelian groups and additive notation the name *sum* is also used.)

When dealing with groups, the set $U^2=UU$ and $U^{-1}=\{u^{-1}; u\in U\}$ are 
often used. More generally, we can also define $U^n$ for any integer $n$. (Here $U\subseteq G$ can be any subset of $G$. Maybe they are encountered even more often when dealing with topological groups and $U$ is a neighborhood of the identity.)

**Question.** Is there a commonly used name for $U^2$ and $U^{-1}$? And perhaps also for $U^n$?

I would guess *inverse of $U$* for $U^{-1}$. But I am not sure whether somethings like *$U$ squared* or *$n$-th power of $U$* is used for $U^2$ and $U^n$.

Comment: I would read it the way it's written: "$U$ squared", "$U$ inverse", "$U$ to the $n$". It's brief, and not liable to cause confusion, given that the written version is also visible to the reader.

Comment: And analogous for the additive case: "two $U$" (or perhaps "$U$ plus $U$"), "minus $U$", "n  $U$" (or perhaps "$U$ plus itself n times")..

Comment: @quasi: With "two $U$" I would rather think of the set $\{2u: u\in U\}$. Which in general will not be the same as $U+U$. For example, $2\mathbb Z$ is the set of even numbers, while $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Right, but if, in the context of a given topological group, the written version is $2U$, and if the audience is advised that it means $U+U$, then there's no confusion in reading it the way it's written (i.e., as "two $U$"). Similarly, if it's written as $U+U$, I would read it as "$U$ plus $U$".